# How do I find the equation of a circle given two tangents and a line which contains its centre but no points

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

How do I find the equation of the circle which touches both the x-axis (that is y = 0 is a tangent) and the line 4x - 3y + 4 = 0, find its centre lies in the first quadrant and on the line x - y - 1 = 0.

The farthest I could go is to draw the diagrams and realize that the circle is actually uniquely determined based on the parameters given. But so far, I have not been able to get the equation.

Comment: Hint: If the x-coordinate of the contact point on the x-axis be $a$, then find its y-coordinate and hence the centre of the circle.

Comment: The center must be on the bisector of the angle between the two tangents

Comment: If the center is $(a, b)$ and the radius is $r$, then: $a - b - 1 = 0 $ and $ r = b = \dfrac{|4 a - 3 b + 4| }{\sqrt{4^2 + 3^2}} $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $P(p,q)$ and $r$ be, respectively, the center of the circle and the line $4x-3y+4=0$.

We know also that $p-q-1=0$, that is, $p=q+1$.

Then
$$d(OX,P)=d(r,P)$$
$$|q|=\frac{|4p-3q+4|}{\sqrt{4^2+3^2}}$$
$$5|q|=|q+8|$$

This yields two different possibilities:

- $5q=q+8\to q=2\to p=3\to P=(3,2)$
- $5q=-q-8\to q=-\frac43\to p=-\frac13\to P=\left(-\dfrac13,-\dfrac43\right)$